# Index and Match not working in a sheet. but the same formula works in the other

Tags: excel

I am having a weird problem with my excel sheet. It is because I have been trying to use the Index(range;Match();column()) to extract information from a big data set.

The problem is that the above formula, when I apply into one sheet, then it shows #REF. But if I copy/paste or connect the data to another sheet and run the index(match()) command there, then it works like it should. Does anyone have any clue what could be the error?

It is because right now I have a data set of almost 800 rows, and I can not connect it to a second sheet, since I dont want to overburden the file. So has anyone ever faced this issue before with their excel files?

I have used the exact method formula in the second sheet and it works. But it is this one sheet where the problem arises. I have been using vlookup() in the same sheet and it worked fine.

UPDATE

I have also uploaded the result now as well.
[image]

Comment: Your first range is 6 columns wide, but you're passing `COLUMN(CY5)` as the column argument, which is 103.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I dont undersstand what you mean by this? Could you write the command so I can see what you mean?

Comment: INDEX has three arguments: 1. the range containing the value you want; 2. the row index (in that range) you want the value from; 3. the column index for that value. If your range is 6 columns wide, the only valid column values for the third argument are 1-6, not 103!

Comment: But I didnt write 103 anywhere? Where are you getting that value from?

Comment: `COLUMN(CY5)` returns the column number of column CY which is 103.

Comment: ahh yes. I just realised the mistake. Thank you!